# What statistical test should I use for a two-test in-group likert scale study?

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, likert

[image]

Participants will take the following survey (with likert-scale questions) twice under two different conditions. What kind of significance test should I perform? I was thinking a t-test, but feel that the likert scales might throw it off. Also, whatever the test is, can I perform it in R or Excel? If so, how? What kind of data visualization should I use?